# Extremely slow AppEngine Blob uploads

Tags: java, performance, google-app-engine, upload, blobstore

I'm seeing a strange slow-down problem with AppEngine: Requests for blob uploads in my app take 2.5-3.5 seconds, even though the blobs are tiny (just a couple hundred bytes). All other requests in my app are serviced in 100-300ms and if I take a look at the logs, the callback request from the blob upload is no exception. So it seems that the blob upload server is taking 2-3seconds to accept the upload, store it, and get around to calling back my app. Seems extremely long, no?

Just to preempt: I know that 100-byte entries in blobstore are a stupid idea and should instead be stored in the regular datastore to reduce overhead, but over time the data in the blobs will grow and then I will have to keep them in blobstore anyways...

Thanks,

Markus

PS: In case it matters: I'm using the Java API...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your app master slave or HRD?

There are quite a few steps that happen when uploading blobs  - including some datastore writes. You should expect it to take longer that a normal http get that is sent to your app.

Comment: Currently it's master slave. Could this make a difference? In my understanding master slave should be faster, right?

It makes sense that a lot is happening during a blob upload, but a 2-3 second delay seems very excessive, no? Maybe this process just hasn't been optimized as much as other things since it is mostly meant for uploads of big files which take a while anyways and 2-3 seconds more don't matter much there?

Comment: to be honest 2 or 3 seconds does not seem excessive to me at all - if you're only have small uploads you can always write a handler to accept a post and use the files api to write out to blobstore if you think it will better suit your application.

Comment: That's not a bad idea. I should try if that's faster. Technically, I don't see a reason why it should make a performance difference, since I would assume that this is exactly what the blob upload handler does, but it probably does anyways. I'm surprised, though, that you think a 2-3s turn-around is not excessive, considering AppEngine (as far as I understand from the docs and the talks at Google I/O) is specifically designed to service request as fast as possible, preferably ~100-ms. Usually latency is quoted as the #1 user-experience-relevant benchmark and 2-3s for no reason seems like a lot.